# Any suggestion please?

Tags: tense

I think i am not good at in English tenses at all, So I am seeking for your kind suggestion to start studying English tenses using any kind of online sources.

Regards

Comment: Does [the Resources for Learning English post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) help?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to get some English manuals to help you. Use of search engines like Google or Wikipedia will also help. There also free eBooks online you can download. For example, you can search Learning English Tenses.PDF. This will bring downloadable materials for you.

Also, there are many English sites for non native English speakers. A search for English Teaching sites on your favorite search engine will bring you many of them. I'll advise you visit as many as possible so as to see the ones that suit you.

But let me give some **tips** on tenses.

Singular nouns and pronouns carry singular verbs and, of course, plural nouns and pronouns carry plural verbs.

For example,

He loves to read. Here, *loves* is a singular verb because of *he,* one person.

They love to read. It will be *love*, a plural verb because of *they,* more than one.

**Please note that** singular verbs carry *s* while plurals do not.

It's expedient to know that first person and second person pronouns are **exempted** from this rule.

for example, *I (first person pronoun)* always carries a plural verb whether plural or singular. 
E.g. *I know* (not, I knows).

Same with *second person (You)*. It's,
*You know (not, you knows).*

**Examples of tenses and various verb forms**

Present tense - I wash

Past tense - I washed

Future tense - I will wash

Present perfect - I have washed

Past perfect - I had washed

Future perfect - I will have washed

Present progressive - I am washing

Past progressive - I was washing

Future progressive - I will be washing

**Topics to search for**

Parts of speech

Gerund

**All the best.**

Comment: First person and second person are excluded from the number(singular or plural) agreement.

Comment: You're right @user178049 for example, *I* (first person pronoun) always carry a plural verb whether plural or singular. E.g. I know *not* I knows. Same with second person (You). It's You know and not you knows.